# Ag Grid Master Detail nested selected row

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Unable to get selected row in AG Grid Master Detail
My main grid contains two more sub grids. Trying to click on 2nd and 3rd level grid and get the selected row but the below code does not work

```
onSelectionChanged(event: SelectionChangedEvent) {
      debugger;
    const selectedData = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
    console.log('Selection updated');
  }


  public detailCellRendererParams: any = {
    // level 2 grid options
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'Name', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' }
      ],
      onSelectionChanged: this.onSelectionChanged.bind(this),
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      groupDefaultExpanded: 0,
      masterDetail: true,
      detailRowHeight: 240,
      detailCellRendererParams: {
        // level 3 grid options
        detailGridOptions: {
         //below method does not get called
          onSelectionChanged: this.onSelectionChanged.bind(this),
          columnDefs: [
            { field: 'RegionName', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' }
          ],
          defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
          },
        },
        getDetailRowData: (params) => {
          params.successCallback(params.data.Regions);
        },
      } as IDetailCellRendererParams,
    },
    getDetailRowData: (params) => {
      params.successCallback(params.data.States);
    },
  } as IDetailCellRendererParams;
```

Please see the below plunkr for reference
[Nested Grid](https://plnkr.co/edit/m8hXofKn1jJ6Z6aU)